# Why won't my WCF service return an integer?

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote a WCF service that reads data from my SQL Server database. It works fine when a call a method that returns all strings, but if I call a method that returns an int it crashes with some error about a timeout and too much data, which doesn't make sense to me...

Here is my web service code:

```
public List<Track> getTrack()
{
    List<Track> trackList = new List<Track>();

    SqlConnection dbConn = connectToDb();

    string _selectQuery = string.Format("SELECT Date, Track, KeyID FROM hdData ORDER BY Track");

    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_selectQuery, dbConn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Track Dat = new Track();
            Dat.Date = (string)reader[0];
            Dat.TrackName = (string)reader[1];
            Dat.KeyId = (int)reader[2];
            trackList.Add(Dat);
        }

        dbConn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }

     return trackList;
  }
```

If I take out the `KeyId` field it works fine... `KeyId` in the database is defined as a type `int` and is an auto incrementing field.

I even tried casting it to a `varchar` but same result...

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Dean

The exact error and Track class is as follows:

Ok, exact error is:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at IService1.getTrack()
>   at Service1Client.getTrack()
>
> Inner Exception:
>   The maximum message size quota for incoming messages
>   (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

And the Track class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class Track
{
    string _Date, _TrackName;
    int _KeyId;

    [DataMember]
    public string Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string TrackName
    {
        get { return _TrackName; }
        set { _TrackName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int KeyId
    {
        get { return _KeyId; }
        set { _KeyId = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give us the exact error ? And also the Track class. You should also close your reader.

Comment: Maybe if you use an MsSql CE database your KeyId is not an int but an GUID. Then you get an error while trying to convert to int.

Comment: Enable [wcf tracing](http://mkdot.net/mknetug/b/dejan/archive/2008/10/23/wcf-tracing-and-message-logging.aspx) to see detailed error message and show us that error.

Comment: Boom posted error and now everything is clear - increase `MaxReceivedMessageSize` in endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "If I take out the KeyId field" do you mean remove from Track class? If so is it possible that the size of your Track list you are returning is close to your endpoint bindings MaxReceivedMessageSize (65536)?  If this was the case then reducing the size of that List by removing a the _KeyId int from the Track class may reduce the overall returned data size below this limit.
Try increasing this limit in the end point binding.  You may need to do this for both server and client. Eg:

```
 maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
        maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000"
        maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
```

Comment: I have increased the maxRecievedMessageSize in my web.config. The problem now is that it doesn't seem to take effect when I publish it to my my web host (www.winhost.com). 

I would have assumed that the web host would have used whatever web.config file I would have published?

Comment: Thats another issue.  I cant really help you there as I only have experience in win service hosting not IIS hosting of WCF servers.  You might be better off posting that as a separate question.

Comment: ok thanks Ricibob, i'll send it through to the winhost team first and see if they can answer.

Comment: BTW this question just popped up - it might help you (either directly with info it contains or when its answered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041931/error-400-bad-request-maxreceivedmessagesize-not-taken-into-account-for-my-wc

Comment: All sorted, thanks guys... it's was all in the web.config file :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to increase the size of your message. To do this, you need to create a **binding configuration** for whatever binding you're using - I'm using `basicHttpBinding` here as an example. So you need to define the binding configuration (both on your server and in your client's config), and your service as well as your clients need to reference that binding configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <!-- use whichever binding you're using here! -->
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <!-- define a binding configuration with a name -->
      <binding name="LargeData"
               maxBufferSize="999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Namespace.YourServiceClass">
      <!-- your endpoints - both on the server as well as on the client - need
           to make reference to that defined binding configuration -->
      <endpoint name="test"
                address="...."
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="LargeData"
                contract="Namespace.IYourServiceContract" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and on client, you'll have this:

```
   <client name="....">
        <endpoint name="test"
            address="...."
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="LargeData"
            contract="Namespace.IYourServiceContract" />
   </client>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting a quota error, it's why I asked you the exact error message.

Please read carefully this link:  http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/08/wcf-performance-best-practices/
Especially the Quota part (but I think the whole article will help you to have a better view on WCF).

Then, don't forget that you have to change these settings (Quota) also on the client side (i.e. refresh web reference once you've updated the server)